# Grails constructors - Setting properties vs mapped arguments

Tags: grails, constructor

Is there a difference in terms of performance (or other objective factors) between calling an empty GORM constructor and setting the properties individually, and mapping the parameters in the constructor?

ie

```
Foo foo = new Foo()
foo.bar = 1
foo.baz = 2
```

vs

```
Foo foo = new Foo(bar: 1, baz: 2)
```

I've always preferred the former, but I'm wondering if the second is more efficient.

Comment: I believe using the map constructor works correctly with data binding, whereas setting properties directly does not. I'm not 100% sure on that, though. This probably only matters if you're setting properties to types different from their declared types (e.g. from form parameters, which will all be strings).

Comment: Since setting properties directly probably doesn't go through any data binding logic, it *probably* is a bit faster, although the performance difference probably wouldn't be significant, especially for a webapp. @OverZealous is right, though - profile your application afterward and, *if necessary*, target specific areas that need performance improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say no **significant** performance difference.  I ran some tests creating 1000 objects each way and each way always took less than 50ms so you're probably splitting hairs at that point.  In both instances the setters (if implemented) are invoked so you're good to go on that front.

I'd go with whatever is easier to read.  As for consistency, yes overall I think it's important, but I would stick with easier to read.  If you're constructing an object with 20 properties, a map may not be the best.  If you're constructing it with 4 properties then maybe it makes sense.

Here are the tests that I ran:

```
@Test
public void performance1() {
    def times = []
    10.times {
        1000.times {
            def startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            def user = new User()
            user.firstName = "Steve"
            user.lastName = "Jobs"
            def endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            times << endTime - startTime
        }
    }
    println "Average: ${times.sum() / 10}"
}

@Test
public void performance2() {
    def times = []
    10.times {
        1000.times {
            def startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    def user = new User(firstName: "Steve", lastName:"Jobs")
            def endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            times << endTime - startTime
        }
    }
    println "Average: ${times.sum() / 10}"
}
```

Comment: I mostly agree — When setting a lot of properties, I would be tempted to use `foo.with{}`, which eliminates all the visual noise of repeating the object.  Alternatively, you could still use the map constructor, just spreading the map out over multiple lines.  This ends up looking similar to the `with` method.  I think that straight `foo.property = value` is rarely the best option.

Comment: Do you happen to still have those tests? This is good fodder for a blog post, giving people the chance to replicate and ensure differences don't change on different platforms or at different scales.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe there is any efficiency gain between the two.  The map constructor (the second one) internally does the same thing.  It might be a tiny bit slower, because it has to loop over the map.

In the real world, the performance won't matter.  More importantly, you are micro-optimizing here, which you really shouldn't do.  Write the app (worrying only about macro-optimizations) first.  If you have actual performance issues, profile and correct them then.

As for which to use, it's truly a personal preference, but most Groovy devs will tell you that the second one is more idiomatic, and easier to read.  It's a lot less typing, too.

Finally, whatever you choose, as always, be consistent!

Comment: You're not the first to make this point and won't be the last.  Readability is the only criterion of interest here... and that's subjective.

Answer (score 2):

I personally verified that for domain classes there is a big hit in terms of performances.

While trying to solve a performance issue, I found this blog entry [Grails Domain Class Creation Performance](http://blog.oio.de/2010/08/05/updated-grails-domain-class-creation-performance-avoid-named-parameters-in-loops-with-many-iterations/), changed from map style constructor invocation and gained a factor on ten when creating a lot of new instances (not to be persisted BTW).

I'm using grails 2.01, so the problem (?) is still there.

Comment: In 2.3.7, the difference is still a factor of 10. Don't use map-based constructors from any massively looping code.